# Change parameter inside button command every loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a for loop which iterates through a list. I have a counter that increases with every loop, which is supplied as the parameter. I want the counter to increase by 1 every loop where it is then supplied as the new parameter for that button command (similar to the original command where each button has a different value).

```
self.airfields_btn = []
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[0]), [260,375]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[1]), [205,270]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[2]), [120,377]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[3]), [170,295]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[4]), [265,355]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[5]), [70,240]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[6]), [180,400]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[7]), [160,420]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[8]), [188,225]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[9]), [155,185]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[10]), [135,142]))
self.airfields_btn.append(ImageButton(self, self.r_vfr, lambda: showinfo(icao_codes[11]), [205,360]))

dd_coords = {
  1: (51.890329772, 0.442831562),
  2: (54.21144, -1.29237),
  3 : (51.8322, -4.7631),
  4: (53.7719, -3.0370),
  5: (52.2046, 0.1743),
  6: (55.1582, -6.7915),
  7: (51.6681, -2.0569),
  8: (50.8600, -3.2347),
  9: (55.2805, -1.7149),
  10: (56.1833, -3.2203),
  11: (57.5425, -4.0475),
  12: (52.0408, -1.0956)
}

def get_location(self, index):
    locx = dd_coords[index][0]
    locy = dd_coords[index][1]
    print(locx)
    print(locy)

 def set_vector(self):
    index = 0
    for items in self.airfields_btn:
      items.config(command = lambda: self.get_location(index))
      index = index + 1
```

However, when I run the code, index is 12 for all the buttons. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the lambda only captures `index` once. You can force it to capture a different one each time:

```py
    items.config(command = lambda index = index: self.get_location(index))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to reverse the command back to the previous one once changed?